# get error on calling put_all from python thin client

Tags: python, thin-client

I am working on the example "create_binary.py", instead of doing put to the cache, I tried `put_all` for multiple records to cache. While `put` is successful, but `put_all` gives error.

```
student_cache = client.get_or_create_cache({
    PROP_NAME: 'SQL_PUBLIC_STUDENT',
    PROP_SQL_SCHEMA: 'PUBLIC',
    PROP_QUERY_ENTITIES: [
        {
            'table_name': 'Student'.upper(),
            'key_field_name': 'SID',
            'key_type_name': 'java.lang.Integer',
            'field_name_aliases': [],
            'query_fields': [
                {
                    'name': 'SID',
                    'type_name': 'java.lang.Integer',
                    'is_key_field': True,
                    'is_notnull_constraint_field': True,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'NAME',
                    'type_name': 'java.lang.String',
                },
                {
                    'name': 'LOGIN',
                    'type_name': 'java.lang.String',
                },
                {
                    'name': 'AGE',
                    'type_name': 'java.lang.Integer',
                },
                {
                    'name': 'GPA',
                    'type_name': 'java.math.Double',
                },
            ],
            'query_indexes': [],
            'value_type_name': 'SQL_PUBLIC_STUDENT_TYPE',
            'value_field_name': None,
        },
    ],
})
```

## put works fine

```
student_cache.put(
1,
Student(LOGIN='jdoe', NAME='John Doe', AGE=17, GPA=4.25),
key_hint=IntObject
)
```

## put_all not working

```
student_cache.put_all({1: Student(LOGIN='jdoe', NAME='John Doe', AGE=17, GPA=4.25), 2: Student(LOGIN='jdoe2', NAME='John Doe2', AGE=18, GPA=4.25)})
```

`put_all` gives error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/ignite/pyignite/examples/create_binary.py", line 105, in 
>       student_cache.put_all({1: Student(LOGIN='jdoe', NAME='John Doe', AGE=17, GPA=4.25), 2: Student(LOGIN='jdoe2', NAME='John Doe2', AGE=18,
>   GPA=4.25)})   File
>   "C:\Users\nbkmqoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pyignite\utils.py",
>   line 169, in ste_wrapper
>       raise exc(result.message) pyignite.exceptions.CacheError: Failed to update keys (retry update if possible).: [1, 2]

How can I make put_all working?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems for put, we need to give a key_hint ( key_hint=IntObject). But for put_all, how do we put the key_hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.
Need to add datatype in the turple with the key

student_cache.put_all({**(1, IntObject)**: Student(LOGIN='jdoe', NAME='John Doe', AGE=17, GPA=4.25), **(2, IntObject)**: Student(LOGIN='jdoe2', NAME='John Doe2', AGE=18, GPA=4.25)})